# Use routerLink with URL that contains encoded slashes (%2F)

Tags: angular

Is there a way to pass a URL to routerLink that contains urlencoded characters like %2F (the encoded slash)? I tried four ways but none of them work.

Given: the string `objects/_%2F_`.

Goal: an `a` element with `href` equal to the input string, just using the angular router.

```
<p><a [routerLink]="'objects/_%2F_'">objects/_%252F_</a></p>

<p><a [routerLink]="['objects/_%2F_']">objects/_%252F_</a></p>

<p><a [routerLink]="[{ segmentPath: 'objects/_%2F_' }]">objects%2F_%252F_</a></p>

<p><a [routerLink]="['', 'objects/_%2F_']">objects%2F_%252F_</a></p>
```

The text contents of the `a` elements in the example are the URLs generated by the respective `routerLink`. I also created a [StackBlitz that showcases the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gqhrfp?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp.component.html).

Bonus points: Use the URL as base, and append e.g. `'_/_'` to get `'objects/_%2F_/_%2F_'` (so that new segment should be escaped)

Background: I calculate the base URL encode, and some path segments of that base URL contain slashes which need to be escaped. Currently, the base URL is passed around as string in my application. I could rewrite it to pass the base URL as individual router commands (as an array of string), but I wonder if there is a way to make this work when the base URL exists as a string.

Comment: I think it's currently not possible to do this in Angular without parsing the URL manually and passing the segments manually to `routerLink`. I opened a feature request, and will post an answer here on StackOverflow if that issue got feedback. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/50950

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a URL to `routerLink`  is currently not supported by Angular natively. There is an [open issue with a feature request to accept an UrlTree, though](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34468).

Here is a pipe that lets you pass a URL consisting of path segments (relative or absolute) to `routerLink`, optionally with further path segments:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Takes an encoded URL and parses it so it can be passed to Router.createUrlTree
 *
 * This can be used to pass an encoded URL to e.g. [routerLink]
 *
 * All arguments are treated as additional path segments.
 */
@Pipe({
    name: 'decodeRouterUrl',
    standalone: true,
})
export class DecodeRouterUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(url: string, ...args: string[]): string[] {
        const urlParts = url.split('/');
        let isAbsolute = false;
        let numberOfDoubleDots = 0;
        const regularCommands: string[] = [];
        urlParts.forEach((urlPart, partIndex) => {
            if (partIndex == 0 && urlPart === '.') {
                // skip './a'
            } else if (partIndex == 0 && urlPart === '') {
                //  '/a'
                isAbsolute = true;
            } else if (urlPart === '..') {
                //  '../a'
                numberOfDoubleDots++;
            } else if (urlPart != '') {
                regularCommands.push(decodeURIComponent(urlPart));
            }
        });

        // put / and .. into the first part because createUrlTree only treats these correctly there
        // if we don't have a special part, specify './', which will be ignored.
        // don't put any regular parts (urlParts and args) into the first command so they are
        // treated literally instead of e.g. being split at slashes
        const specialPart = isAbsolute ? '/' : './' + '../'.repeat(numberOfDoubleDots);
        return [specialPart, ...regularCommands, ...args];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```html
<a [routerLink]=['objects/_%2F_' | decodeRouterUrl]>link</a>
```

[Here is a StackBlitz with the pipe, unit tests, and an example usage.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xenaeb?file=src%2Fdecode-router-url.pipe.spec.ts,src%2Fdecode-router-url.pipe.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have url encoded route names defined in your router, then you can use `_%2F_test` as example:

```
 provideRouter([
      { path: '_%2F_test', component: TestComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]),
```

If your route looks like this:

```
 provideRouter([
      { path: '_/_test', component: TestComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]),
```

then you can use a little helper method:

#### ts

```
  decode(url: string) {
    return decodeURIComponent(url);
  }
```

#### html

```
<p><a [routerLink]="[decode('_%2F_test')]">_/_test</a></p>
```

I hope this helps.

##### Note

In your example (Stackblitz) are no routes defined.. Your `provideRouter`has an empty array. And you not using `<router-outlet>`!

### Update

Change your code part in `main.ts` with this:

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  template: 'Key: {{key}} (wanted: _/_)',
})
class RoutedComponent {
  key: string | null = null;

  decode(url: string) {
    return decodeURIComponent(url);
  }

  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    route.params.subscribe((d) => (this.key = this.decode(d.key)));
  }
}
```

You will see the correct "key".

Comment: I initially left out the route for simplicity sake, but maybe that made it harder to understand. I updated the question and the StackBlitz with a route `objects/:key` and the goal to navigate to `objects/_%2F_` (so the `:key` includes a slash). Note that `decodeURIComponent('objects/_%2F_') === 'objects/_/_'`, so that call would make the encoded and the non-encoded slash the same, but they need to stay different.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly: In the RoutedComponent, you wanna have the key with the Value: `"_/_"`?

Comment: yes exactly, I want the `objects/:key` route to match with the string `"_/_"` as value for the `key` path param

Comment: Then you can use the method in my answer: `decode(url: string) {
    return decodeURIComponent(url);
  }` You get the param, decode it and you have your expected result `"_/_"`

Comment: You mean calling `decode` before passing the URL to `routerLink`? That would not work, because `decodeURIComponent('objects/_%2F_') ===  'objects/_/_'`, and if I pass that to `routerLink`, the path param will be `'_'`.

Comment: Double-decoding is not a fix. The URLs are still wrong, and it's hard to generate the double-encoded URLs in other places (e.g. I would need to manually encode the key when passing it as an additional path segment to `routerLink`, see my "bonus points" paragraph.

I'm afraid there is no straightforward solution at the moment. There is an open [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34468) though, and I'll also post my intermediate solution here as an answer. Thank you for your suggestions in any case!